# Can I use the word "thereof" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I know the general meaning and use of the word "thereof" in a sentence, but I was wondering if the word could be used at the beginning of a sentence like in the following example. (I didn't find this example anywhere; I've just made it up.)

> Yesterday Mary went to town to buy some flowers. Thereof I couldn't
> find any trace.

Since "thereof" means "of that/of which" the sentence would mean:

> Yesterday Mary went to town to buy some flowers, of which I couldn't
> find any trace.

Now, I'm not asking if this usage is common—I know it isn't. What I want to know is whether it is grammatically correct—or shall we say permissible—if used in a literary/poetic context.

Comment: I would use _whereof_ for _of which_, but it would be more acceptable as a single sentence. I don't think you can begin a sentence with _thereof_.

Comment: Google NGrams is case-sensitive, so you can [***draw your own conclusions***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thereof%2CThereof&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthereof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThereof%3B%2Cc0) from that NGram showing capitalised ***Thereof*** positively "flatlining" against ***thereof***. But it's also worth noting just how far the usage has declined over the past couple of centuries. Unless you actually *want* to sound like a Victorian, you shouldn't even be *thinking* about using the word ***thereof**!*

Comment: The answer is no, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Thereof follows something (it means 'of the thing just mentioned; of that'), and cannot, logically, begin a sentence. Whereof we cannot speak, thereof we must remain silent. "The member state or a part thereof".